# What are all the different methods of taking a screenshot of a webbrowser control

Tags: c#, c++, windows, browser, screenshot

There seem to be several differe method of taking screenshot of a webbrowser control: BiBlt, Printwindow, etc. There seem to be several ways, and all have different pros and cons.  Does anyone have detailed info of each of these options and their pros and cons?

I am mainly looking for method that would work when the OS is locked, and also the screen/control is not the top most window - or visible tab. The current method we use, IViewObject.Draw, takes blank/black screenshots sometimes - so is not solid.

Comment: Unless you're on Vista/7 with Aero enabled, Windows isn't going to maintain the contents of windows that are obscured, so attempting to grab a screenshot of them will usually get you garbage or a partially-blanked image.